# How to change back the player's default color in chat

Tags: lua, roblox

I've been learning how to change the player's chat color and tags, the only thing I want to achieve now is to change it back to the default

Here's the code *(I'm only gonna include the important ones)*

```lua
ceValue.Changed:Connect(function() 
    local player = game.Players:WaitForChild(ceValue.Value)
    local character = player.Character

    while character do
        if chatService ~= nil then
            local speaker = chatService:GetSpeaker(player.Name)

            repeat wait(1)
                speaker = chatService:GetSpeaker(player.Name)
            until speaker ~= nil            

            speaker:SetExtraData("NameColor", ceColor)
            speaker:SetExtraData("ChatColor", ceColor)

            if ceValue.Value == "" then
                for i, v in pairs(game.Players:GetChildren()) do
                    speaker = chatService:GetSpeaker(v.Name)

                    --///HERE'S WHERE I WANT TO CHANGE THE PLAYER'S CHAT COLOR///---
                end

                break
            end

            wait(0.5)
        end
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Chat Speaker is assigned a color on its creation based off its username. This way, each Speaker won't get a different color if they leave and join another game.

There are a couple of different methods where you can retrieve a default color of a speaker.

## Getting the Default Color

### Save It

Once the player joins, you can cache their color and then allow them to modify it. For this method, you have to make sure that you don't allow the player to modify their color beforehand - otherwise, you'll end up saving the wrong color.

This code snippet would grab what would be their default color and store that instead using `ComputeNameColor(player.Name)` from the `chatService`.

```lua
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
 
Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local color = ComputeNameColor(player.Name)
    
    local colorObj = Instance.new("Color3Value")
    colorObj.Name = "DefaultChatColor"
    colorObj.Value = color
    colorObj.Parent = player
end)
```

*Chat colors do consist of `BrickColor` and `Color3` values, but the [`BrickColor.new("x").Color`](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/datatype/BrickColor) property used in Roblox's color dictionary to reference these `BrickColor` items will convert them into a `Color3` anyway.*

Later on, you can retrieve the chat color again by just calling for the `player.DefaultChatColor.Value`.

### Regenerate It

If you can't retrieve the color from the Color3Value, you can always generate the default color of a speaker the same way Roblox does - performing math on the username! You'll want to call `GetNameColor(Speaker)` to get a speaker's team/default color, or `ComputeNameColor(player.Name)` if you want to ignore teams altogether.

The code that generates the default colors is present within `game.Chat.DefaultChatModules.ExtraDataInitializer` on lines 86-127 (where it looks like this code is running inside due to the variable names), but you can clone it if you're working inside a GUI or somewhere else:

```lua
local NAME_COLORS =
{
  Color3.new(253/255, 41/255, 67/255), -- BrickColor.new("Bright red").Color,
  Color3.new(1/255, 162/255, 255/255), -- BrickColor.new("Bright blue").Color,
  Color3.new(2/255, 184/255, 87/255), -- BrickColor.new("Earth green").Color,
  BrickColor.new("Bright violet").Color,
  BrickColor.new("Bright orange").Color,
  BrickColor.new("Bright yellow").Color,
  BrickColor.new("Light reddish violet").Color,
  BrickColor.new("Brick yellow").Color,
}
local function GetNameValue(pName)
  local value = 0
  for index = 1, #pName do
    local cValue = string.byte(string.sub(pName, index, index))
    local reverseIndex = #pName - index + 1
    if #pName%2 == 1 then
      reverseIndex = reverseIndex - 1
    end
    if reverseIndex%4 >= 2 then
      cValue = -cValue
    end
    value = value + cValue
  end
  return value
end
local color_offset = 0
local function ComputeNameColor(pName)
  return NAME_COLORS[((GetNameValue(pName) + color_offset) % #NAME_COLORS) + 1]
end
local function GetNameColor(speaker)
  local player = speaker:GetPlayer()
  if player then
    if player.Team ~= nil then
      return player.TeamColor.Color
    end
  end
  return ComputeNameColor(speaker.Name)
end
```

## Applying

Applying the new, or old in this case, chat color should be identical to what you've done in the code already: using `speaker:setExtraData("(x)Color", oldColor)`.

### "Regenerate It"

```lua
ceValue.Changed:Connect(function() 
    local player = game.Players:WaitForChild(ceValue.Value)
    local character = player.Character

    while character do
        if chatService ~= nil then
            local speaker = chatService:GetSpeaker(player.Name)

            repeat wait(1)
                speaker = chatService:GetSpeaker(player.Name)
            until speaker ~= nil            

            speaker:SetExtraData("NameColor", ceColor)
            speaker:SetExtraData("ChatColor", ceColor)

            if ceValue.Value == "" then
                for i, v in pairs(game.Players:GetChildren()) do
                    speaker = chatService:GetSpeaker(v.Name)

                    defColor = GetNameColor(Speaker)
                    speaker:SetExtraData("NameColor", defColor)
                    speaker:SetExtraData("ChatColor", defColor)
                end

                break
            end

            wait(0.5)
        end
    end
end)
```

### "Store it!"

```lua
ceValue.Changed:Connect(function() 
    local player = game.Players:WaitForChild(ceValue.Value)
    local character = player.Character

    while character do
        if chatService ~= nil then
            local speaker = chatService:GetSpeaker(player.Name)

            repeat wait(1)
                speaker = chatService:GetSpeaker(player.Name)
            until speaker ~= nil            

            speaker:SetExtraData("NameColor", ceColor)
            speaker:SetExtraData("ChatColor", ceColor)

            if ceValue.Value == "" then
                for i, v in pairs(game.Players:GetChildren()) do
                    speaker = chatService:GetSpeaker(v.Name)

                    local cachedCol = v:FindFirstChild("DefaultChatColor")
                    if cachedCol ~= nil then
                        --There's a cache found.
                        speaker:SetExtraData("NameColor",cachedCol.Value)
                        speaker:SetExtraData("ChatColor",cachedCol.Value)
                    end
                end

                break
            end

            wait(0.5)
        end
    end
end)
```

Hope this helps!